# Mongodb - match all items in array of strings field

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying match documents where all items in field colors included in query list provided.

```
   {id: 1, colors: ["red"] },
   {id: 2, colors: ["blue", "red"] },
   {id: 3, colors: ["red", "blue", "green" ] },
   {id: 4, colors: ["black", "blue", "green" ] },
```

if the query `[red]` it should match items `1` if query `[red, blue]` it should match `1,2` if query `[blue, green, red]` it should match `1,2,3`

all items in colors field should be in the query list

How can I do it in Mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- i think you want colors to be subset of the query

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63263c0878a49d87828514b9)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$setIsSubset": ["$colors", ["red", "blue"]]}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay,

This solves the second half of my implementation for subscription/notification.
user can subscribe for tags on post, every subscription is a list of strings like so
`[
 ["cityName", "flat", "rent"],
["cityName", "car", "sale", "honda"],
["car", "sale"],
[ "electronics", "tv", "sale"]
]`

with your answer the server can send notification on new post if the list of tags in post match any of subscription arrays for the user

now how can I fetch the list of posts base on subscription arrays of the user, so user can see all related posts on his feeds.

Thanks

Comment: i am confused a bit, i think it will be easier to create another question, with the new data, what query should do, and the expected output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73759299/9487632

Comment: can you please tell about this solution if it is efficient ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73759299/9487632