# Mongodb - match field ( array of strings ) with query of multi lists of strings

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb

let say post has multi tag array field :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Tv for sale",
    "city":"doha",
    "tags": ["doha", "tv", "sale", "used" ]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "flat for rent",
    "city":"dubai",
    "tags": ["dubai", "flat", "rent" ]
}
```

and user subscriptions as follow:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user1",
    "subscriptions": [["doha", "tv", "used"],["dubai", "flat", "sale"]]
  }
```

how can I in Mongodb get the list of posts based on user subscriptions.
so the user gets the posts where any of his subscriptions is fully included in post tags.

in this case, only post with `id:1` will be returned

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways this could be done.  Here's one way.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "posts",
      "let": {
        "subs": "$subscriptions"
      },
      "as": "posts",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$$subs",
                "initialValue": false,
                "in": {
                  "$or": [
                    "$$value",
                    {"$setIsSubset": ["$$this", "$tags"]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mOD8bQcaYuH).

Comment: thanks for your answer, can I get aggregation from post collection only,  with query as list of lists, without include user collection in aggregation.

Comment: @EmadJumaah Sure!  That's even easier.  Just use the `"$match"` portion shown above and replace `"$$subs"` with your array of arrays of strings.

Comment: can you tell if this type of query efficient in case where we have million posts and subscriptions array with length of 500 ?  - the inner array max length of 15,

Comment: @EmadJumaah its very slow i think, but i cant think now of way getting it faster, maybe think if possible to change your schema so an index is used in the lookup. Here no index is used and each lookup involves search in array and set operations.

Comment: @EmadJumaah To use a multikey index on `"tags"`, you could `db.posts.find({"tags": {"$in": aSingleSubscriptionArray}})` (or a similar `"$match"` in an aggregation pipeline).  You would need to iterate through each `users` `"subscriptions"` array. Alternatively, you could generate a set union of all the `user` `"subscriptions"` and then perform one `find`.

Comment: @EmadJumaah  Actually no, my alternative "set union" comment above is not correct as that would probably return `posts` that are unwanted.  I believe my other comment about iterating through `users` `"subscriptions"` array is correct though.

Comment: @rickhg12hs 
thanks for your feed back, I will use the solution above (first solution) and use redis to cache user feed for later use.